# Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null

Tags: mongodb, lumen, jenssegers-mongodb

I am getting Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null when importing data from "Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel" using lumen and MongoDB.

Comment: in /var/www/html/project/vendor/illuminate/database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php (line 175)


protected function handleBeginTransactionException(Throwable $e)    {        if ($this->causedByLostConnection($e)) {            $this->reconnect();            $this->getPdo()->beginTransaction();        } else {            throw $e;        }    }

Comment: I think your problem can be solved by checking this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70666355/error-call-to-a-member-function-begintransaction-on-null