# Error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I am getting:

> Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null

when importing data from `Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel` in Laravel and MongoDB. It's working fine on local but when I am running it on the server it's showing me this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think:

after install run:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider" --tag=config
```

then config file excel.php in config directory

Comment: Thank you! but what confrigation has to done on excel.php

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue.

set transaction handler to null in execl.php

```
'transactions' => [
        'handler' => 'null'
       ]
```

then run
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider" --tag=config